# nginx url index.php/page/Gallery.html returns 404

Tags: php, nginx

sorry if this is a repeat, please just link me if so.

this is my first time setting up nginx. (its under virtualmin and debian)

**it serves php fine, such as index.php**

**but the url index.php/page/Gallery.html returns 404**

im guessing it can't decipher the request string but not sure what to do about it

i dont believe in that form it is using rewrite (something i will setup once i get without working)

its nginx/0.7.67 and the error log message is:

> 2013/01/13 16:19:47 [error] 5170#0: *123 open() "/public_html/index.php/page/Profile.html" failed (20: Not a directory), client: ip, server: .com.au, request: "GET /index.php/page/Profile.html HTTP/1.1", host: ".com.au", referrer: "http://.com.au/"

THANKS !

edit: add conf:

```
server {
server_name ....com.au www.....com.au;
listen 118.8...;
root /home/.../public_html;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
access_log /var/log/virtualmin/....com.au_access_log;
error_log /var/log/virtualmin/....com.au_error_log;
fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/.../public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/.../public_html;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
}
```

}

Comment: You have no rewrite set up at all?  That would be the problem.  See: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

Comment: this may highlight my newbness but do i need them at this stage with this url ? ive add the server conf from virtualmin

Comment: With no rewrite set up it's behaving exactly as apache would and reads `/public_html/index.php/page/Profile.html` as a folder structure but it knows that `index.php` is a file hence the error.  You need to rewrite everything to the right of `index.php` to be passed as a query string.  Are you using a framework?

Comment: yes jaws cms http://www.jaws-project.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use this

> try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

What this would do is try to find the file or the directory, and if neither is found, fall back to the index.php file. That way you could just use `domain.com.au/page/Gallery.html` (assuming there isn't a file with that name). Then you would just use the index.php to load the data. You could also then use it to handle 404 errors, making users see a nice page themed the same as the rest of the site.

However, if you have to use it in that format, you could change it to this

```
location ~ \index.php/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
}
```

This will retain a handler for .php files, while also give you a separate one for when the url contains `index.php/`.

Comment: this worked, but im still a bit confused why i needed this when on apache this url works without a .htaccess, is it that apache already has a rule like this built in ?

Comment: Apache is much more entwined with PHP (at least in the usual distributions that don't use fcgi), so it's a bit better at detecting php files and what should be run by what. Nginx only does what you tell it to, which is, from a security standpoint, a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

with a bit of experimenting i got the provided answer to work when not using index.php 's in jaws cms (rewrite enabled)

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
}
location ~ \index.php/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
}
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/  /index.php/$uri;  
}
```